# Use Mono.Android in my PCL Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, xamarin, reference, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I create a little project whitch use a public SDK DLL for a Android Device (RS30 (it's a barcode scanner))

And in this SDK DLL i can change a BeepSound (for example) when i gonna scan the barcode.

But, in my PCL, when i want to create an interface like this:

```
public interface IScannerService
{
    void StartService();

    void Test(BeepType beep);
}
```

I can't use BeepType because the SDK DLL use Mono.Android:

[image]

And my question is:
How can i use/import or whatever to use BeepType with Mono.Android in my PCL Xamarin Forms.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use [DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/) to call your platform specific code from within your Forms PCL.  You will need to define a custom type or enum to map to BeepType.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You must define a new enum in the PCL (could be a copy of BeepType), and convert from it in your interface implementation.